# Does Gmail POP3 access include emails fetched with POP3?

Tags: gmail, pop3

If I have a Gmail account fetching POP3 email from another source, and I use Outlook Express to access my email with POP3, will I be able to access email messages in Outlook Express that come in through POP3? That already came in through POP3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will as long as I select the "for all mail ever" POP option in gmail settings.